# excavator badge did not add in my account

Tags: support, badges

In my dash board i am seeing the recommendation "excavator"  -Edited first post that was inactive for 6 months.  I have edited [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/329899/what-happened-if-cfilewrite-throws-an-exception)

But i did not receive the badge. I am little bit confused on this excavator badge.

Can any one help me to understand why i did not receive this badge ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Badges can take a little while to get awarded. You only made the edit a few minutes ago, so the script to award it probably just hasn't run yet.

Give it half an hour or so, and it should probably be there. Worst case, check again tomorrow.